# Notation - Comparing Values Within Two Sets

Tags: notation

I do not have a background in mathematics. However, I do empirical research and I oftentimes have difficulties finding the correct mathematical notations for certain things I want to express:

I am comparing two sets of values. Each value in one set relates to a certain value in the other set, i.e. the two sets represent a set of "pairs". How do I express that, e.g. more than half of the values in one set are larger than their respective counterpart in the other set?

Comment: Is this related to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634515/notation-comparing-two-vectors)?

Comment: The two questions are related, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the two sets be $A$ and $B$; the wording implies that they are finite. You say that all the elements can be paired, so there is a bijective function $f:A\mapsto B$ expressing this relation. Call the cardinality of each set $n$.

Your last sentence may then be written as
$$|\{a\in A:a>f(a)\}|>\frac n2$$

Comment: Does a similar notation hold for vectors? For example, if A and B are vectors, does the notation still hold?

Comment: @shenflow I suppose so, if you regarded vectors as ordered multisets.

Comment: Alright. So using a different notation for vectors, one could say $f: \vec{A} \mapsto \vec{B}$, etc.....? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @shenflow I would put $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ or something similar.

Comment: Okay. So you would put that. Then say that the two vectors are elements of the domain and codomain respectively. And then say $$|\{a\in A:a>f(a)\}|>\frac n2$$ to express that more than half of the elements in A are larger than their counterpart in B? Sorry if this gets to extensive, maybe I should post this as a question on its own.

Comment: @shenflow I think you should post this as another question. Don't let the discussion here drag for too long.

Comment: I specified my question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634515/notation-comparing-two-vectors I would be grateful for any help on that. Thank you Parcly.