# Notation - Comparing Two Vectors

Tags: notation, vectors

I work empirically. I estimate two models (of some sort) $n$ times each. Each estimation gives me one value. I thus get $n$ values, two times (two empirical estimations). Each of the $n$ values of the first estimation is related to exactly one of the $n$ values of the second estimation, i.e. each value resulting from one model has a sort of "counterpart" that results from the other model.

(1) Am I right by assuming that these $n$ values each represent a vector, i.e. I am looking at two vectors of $n$ values each?

(2) How do I express that a certain amount of the values in the first vector is larger than their counterpart in the second vector? For example, how do I say that more than half of the elements of the first vector are larger than their respective counterpart in the second vector?

Comment: A vector is an element of a vector space.  This means that vectors may be added together, and multiplied by scalars.  If you are not adding and multiplying these lists of numbers in some way, then it is better to refer to them as *tuples* (or *$n$-tuples* if the length is important to keep track of).

Comment: Why is this regarded as better?

Comment: "Better" in what context?  What is "better" depends on what you want to do with a thing.  Are you adding these things together?  Are you scaling them?  Then they are vectors.  If you aren't doing these things, then you aren't treating them like vectors, and should call them such.  They are ordered lists, or *tuples*.